# Custom Email Template in Magento2

Tags: magento2, template, email, css

I'm trying to create a custom email template.

I have loaded header and I want to start styling it. For example a simple red background color.

Where do I need to add the style?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">
    {{var template_styles|raw}}

    {{css file="css/email.css"}}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}

<!-- Begin wrapper table -->
 <table class="wrapper" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
        <table class="main" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="header">
                    <a class="logo" href="{{store url=""}}">
                        <img
                            {{if logo_width}}
                                width="{{var logo_width}}"
                            {{else}}
                                width="180"
                            {{/if}}

                            {{if logo_height}}
                                height="{{var logo_height}}"
                            {{else}}
                                height="52"
                            {{/if}}

                            src="{{var logo_url}}"
                            alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                            border="0"
                        />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="main-content">
                <!-- Begin Content -->
```

Comment: u can find it in <Magento_Blank_theme_dir>/web/css/

Comment: i am facing same issue http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134160/magento-2-add-call-css-file-in-email-template-of-custom-module

Answer (score 2):

## The way to create a custom template in magento 2 :

Create a module in code :

> app/code//<Module_Name>

Add the `registration.php`, `README.mk` and `etc/module.xml` files.

### Create the config file

In `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/etc` add a `config.xml` file :

> app/code//<Module_Name>/etc/config.xml :

---

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <custom>
            <email>
                <signature_template>custom_email_signature_template</signature_template>
            </email>
        </custom>
    </default>
</config>
```

### Create template declaration

In `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/etc` add a `email_templates.xml` file :

`app/code/<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/etc/email_templates.xml` :

---

Here, I use `Magento_Email`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_email_signature_template" label="Signature" file="signature.html" type="html" module="Magento_Email" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

### Create html template (in the module your need it, for example Magento_email)

In `app/design/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_email/email/` add a
`signature.html` file ex in Magento_Email:

> app/design///<Magento_email>/email/signature.html :

---

Put the HTML you what in.

### Use it

Now, you can call it in in your email :

```
{{template config_path="custom/email/signature_template"}}
```

Comment: HI, I get this error message:
`Error filtering template: Email template 'custom_email_signature_template' is not defined.` Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Does not work, I also get the filtering template error

Answer (score 1):

All css for email are in 
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/css/source/_email-base.less`

Answer (score 1):

The best place to add your styles is in

```
app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/web/css/source/_email-extend.less
```

As these styles will then be automatically inlined by Magento when sent.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link for Styles for email templates: 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#email-styles

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles

The `Magento_Email_module_dir/view/frontend/email/header.html` file contains an inline CSS directive:

The inline CSS directive tells Magento which files to apply as inline styles on the email template.

```
{{inlinecss file="css/email-inline.css"}}
```

For example, let’s say an email is being sent from a store configured with the Magento Luma theme. The inlinecss directive first looks for a email-inline.less file in this file:

```
Magento_Luma_theme_dir/web/css/email-inline.less
```

However because that file doesn’t exist, it will fall back to the `Magento_Blank_theme_dir/web/css/email-inline.less` file. The contents of that file will then be compiled and its contents are applied as inline styles to the email template.

Comment: This mechanism only working in theme base not module base when you put css in custom module it's not working.

Comment: Ok, are you using a custom theme? If so, did you try this files on the custom theme's css directory **/web/css/email-inline.css** @pratik

Comment: yes i am using custom theme. yes i try to put css in my theme web folder but not luck.

Answer (score 0):

**- Create the Config file**

***app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <custom>
            <email>
                <footer_unsubscribe_mail>footer_unsubscribe</footer_unsubscribe_mail>
            </email>
        </custom>
    </default>
</config>
```

**- Create Email Template Declaration**

***app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/etc/email_templates.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="footer_unsubscribe" label="Footer Unsubscribe" file="footer-unsubscribe.html" type="html" module="Vendor_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**- Create HTML Template**

***app/code/Vendor/ModuleName/view/frontend/email/footer-unsubscribe.html***

**- You can call it in your email template**

```
{{template config_path="custom/email/footer_unsubscribe_mail"}}
```