# magento 2 add/call css file in email template of custom module

Tags: magento2, module, email, email-templates, less-css

I am trying to add inline CSS in the email template in my custom module.
Example

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css">
        {{var template_styles|raw}}

        {{css file="css/email.css"}}
    </style>
</head>
```

I reviewed some other modules in Magento 2 for reference like Ebizmarts but **no one adds CSS file in the email template he just written all CSS code in the email template instead of adding a new file.**
I am not sure what is an issue. Looking for help...

Answer (score 2):

Well, the main reason you didn't find anyone adding a link to CSS file in the template is explained in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#email-styles

> **Some email clients (for example, Gmail) support only CSS styles that
>   have been applied as “inline” styles** on the style attribute of HTML
>   tags. Because of this, the majority of email styles are applied as
>   inline styles.

Thus, **if you want to be sure your email is compatible with every email clients, I suggest you add inline CSS directly in the template instead of adding a link to a CSS file**. Feel free to check out the official documentation for more details.

Comment: i create module so write inline css not good idea i open isue on magento 2 git hub forum regarding this issue thax.

Comment: @Pratik well it's not a Magento issue right ? It is the email clients like Gmail which don't support non inline CSS. I highly doubt you want your emails to be unreadable by Gmail right ?

Comment: this is not email client issue if i put same css in theme folder its fallback and it's working but when i put in my cusom module and calling in email template it's not apply. git hub issue link for magento 2 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4438

Comment: @Pratik the issue you send me has been closed, you won't get any answers there. Feel free to open a new one